# Trying to implement nested TabLayouts - Tab with its tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm trying to create an activity like on the image below:

[image]

I have a main `TabLayout` and I want one of its fragments (the one in `Tab2`) to be an other `TabLayout`.

My question is how can I create the fragment `Frag2.java` (as seen in the code below) so that it can implement its own `ViewPager` and a `TabLayout` in order to create the nested tabs.

I don't want to use a `TabHost` because I want all tabs to allow swiping.

The `xml` for the main `TabLayout`( my `Activity`)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#212121"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#46bedc"
        android:background="#212121"
        android:fillViewport="false" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's my **`Activity.java`**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.test.fragments.Frag1;
import com.test.fragments.Frag2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Frag1(), getString(R.string.frag1));
    adapter.addFragment(new Frag2(), getString(R.string.frag2));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

and the Frag1.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.test.R;

public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should have a fragment with `ViewPager` and `tabLayout` and then that Fragment will have more fragments with `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`

Comment: Have you got solution for it? If yes, please post link or solution.

Comment: Thanks @AnshulTyagi for comment.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani do you have any issue in `ViewPager` or `TabLayout`?

Comment: Yes there is issue. How to disable swipe between 2 tabs? I tried many answers but didn't get success. And How to replace one fragment with another fragment in ViewPager ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible use google i belive u will find solution.

I have another solution it is:
when u will open flag2(flag2 will like flag1 but add on onCreateView(..) Intent to go activity of flag2) and create activity of flag2 on the activty add viewpaper and wht u want

Comment: I tried. The problem is that viewpager requires a fragment with its onCreateView. But my Frag2 must me a FragmentActivity and not a Fragment in order to call is own fragments. FragmentActivity has onCreate and not onCreateView